# Why do stock (and forex) prices change over weekend, when the market is supposed to be closed?

Tags: stocks, investing, foreign-exchange

I am checking out Apple's stock on TradingView on a Sunday night and it shows its price fluctuating? How is that possible? Isn't the stock market supposed to be closed on weekends?
Same with forex. If I open EUR/USD, its price has also been fluctuating throughout the entire weekend, even though the market is closed.

Comment: Your night is daytime somewhere else, as is your weekend - arabic countries have their weekend on Fri & Sat, Sun is a normal workday…

Comment: But if the NASDAQ is closed on Sunday, it is closed for everyone. No one should be able to trade Apple's stock

Comment: Apple is not _exclusively_ traded on the NASDAQ. What would you think keeps Jim and Jack in Australia (or China) from trading their Apple shares with each other when they feel like?

Comment: @Aganju Well, for instance, if AAPL were not listed on an Australian stock exchange, that would do it...Are you sure AAPL is listed in on an Australian exchange, and on a Chinese one? I looked for a few minutes but it seems hard to find this data. I do think I could confirm London.

Comment: @KevinArlin I think Aganju's point is that stock exchanges do not have to be open in order for two parties to trade with each other. It's like a vegetable market; the vegetable market could be closed, but you could still buy vegetables from some other channel (e.g. private agreement).

Comment: @Flux Uh, sure, if these guys in Australia are passing paper stock certificates to each other, and then somehow reporting their pricing online...Seems more than a bit irrelevant.

Comment: @Flux but aren't stock exchange prices set for trades on that stock exchange specifically? Apple is traded on multiple stock exchanges, but I am talking about NASDAQ specifically. NASDAQ is closed for everyone right now, but the prices are still changing

Comment: @evilmonster18 sure but inter market pricing is kept in line by shrewd arbitrage traders who have access to both exchanges and are willing to take a little risk.

Comment: @quid arbitrage traders who cannot trade on the exchange when it's closed...

Comment: @user253751 Willing to take a little risk [and wait until one market reopens]

Comment: @quid and so the arbitrage traders cannot affect the price on the closed market, correct?

Comment: I was responding to this:  `but aren't stock exchange prices set for trades on that stock exchange specifically?`  Interexchange arb keeps interexchange pricing close.  I'm not commenting on why a published exchange price is changing.  If one exchange gets out of whack, it represents an opportunity for people with access to multiple exchanges.